Plume de Nom, rather than Nom de Plume
What does Harold Finch mean when he says:

It's written on this. My plume de nom, rather than nom de plume.

This scene occurs in Person of Interest, season 1, episode 10 at 34 minutes, and 58 seconds in.
nom de plume means "pen name" in French (literally "name of feather"). Is plume de nom a wordplay meaning that it's a pen (which used to consist of a feather/quill) with his name on it?

Actually nom de plume is an English-language coinage (using the old-fashioned French word for a (quill) pen).

The pen I write my name with?  Anyway, as @Joachim says, it's a play on words.

Unfamiliar with the series I looked up a little more background information and found it on TVTropes, as an instance of the Don't Explain The Joke trope:

Finch poses as a blogger named Thomas Paine, which he admits is a pseudonym (his "nom de plume"). A few moments later, he offers someone a pen with his name and phone number on it and explains that it's his "Plume de nom..... rather than nom de plume."

So yes, your interpretation is right.
A nom de plume is a "pen name" or pseudonym. The plume - the feather originally used to write one's name in ink - in this case is a fountain pen which has the author's real name engraved on it. Hence they refer to it as their plume de nom ("feather/pen of the name"): not their 'name of writing' but their 'tool for writing their name'.
It doesn't make complete sense, since the pen can still be used as the plume to write their pen name with, and the pen itself has intrinsically nothing to do with the name engraved on it, convoluting the plume with the nom. But it sounds quite intellectual, and I guess that's what the writers went for.

...and Paine -> pen... Sounds like Tweety bird and its romulian:)

"Fountain pen" is still called "stylo plume" or just "plume" in French.

The same reversal works similarly in English — he could call it his name pen (analogously to a name card).

Instead of the (false) name used for his pen (writings), this is an actual pen with his (actual) name upon it.

@RalphJ Not his actual name in this case, Harold Finch is posing as someone and that name is on the pen. Of course, it's also an open question in the show whether Harold Finch is his real name either.

Since you say the pen has his name on it, it's his "name pen", or plume de nom.  My "Dad joke" sense approves of that little joke.
